# how to display selected values apex:selectList as selected

Tags: visualforce

I wanted to save some multiselected values stored in a custom setting and then retrieve the value and display as selected in the selectList.

The first option of saving the value in custom setting is working but i am not sure how we can get the values as selected.

Any pointers on how this can be done would be a great help.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsiStatus">
                <apex:outputlabel value="Don’t Show Leads with Status"  id="lblStatus" /> 
                <apex:selectList id="selectStatus" value="{!cls.Dont_Show_Lead_With_Status__c}" multiselect="true" styleClass="convstatus" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!statusList}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The saved value is stored as `[Closed - Converted, Working - Contacted]`

Update:
As suggested by @Keith, i am changing the way to store in the custom setting as `Working - Contacted; Open - Not Contacted` by removing the "[" and "]" and delimiter as semi-colon instead of comma.

I still cant see the values as default selected when i view the VF page.

Update 2:
If i select just 1 item from the selectList then i can see the value is selected. But there is no selection if more than one option is selected.

Answer (score 6):

In your controller initialize `Dont_Show_Lead_With_Status__c` to all the option values (obtained from your custom setting) separated with a semi-colon using something like:

```
String[] optionValues = ...;

cls.Dont_Show_Lead_With_Status__c = String.join(optionValues, ';');
```

so they are all pre-selected.

**PS** Just saw you addition about the format they are stored in; I've only every seen the semi-colon used to separate the multiple selected values.

Comment: I guess i can change the way its saved to use semi-colon. I have also used multiselect and it saved into database seperated by semi-colon but all of those were saving into a picklist value and not a Text datatype

Comment: @Prady Right, I was assuming the field was of multi-select picklist type.

Comment: i can see the selected value is selected if there is only one option selected, but none are preselected if there is more than one option selected. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @Prady My guess is that packing the selections in separated by semi-colons is tied to the field type not the `multiselect="true"`. Suggest you change the field type.

Comment: unfortunately i am tied up with custom settings  . And i dont have an option of using picklist in a custom setting.

Comment: @Prady I think you can make the field be of the right type and just add a single fake picklist value but keep on populating from your custom settings. There is no validation against the existing picklist values.

Comment: mmm.. thats a good idea.. Let me try that

Answer (score 1):

The Multiselect picklist is just the list of string. So `cls.Dont_Show_Lead_With_Status__c` can take list of string as parameter.

In your constructor,

```
List<String> dontshowstatus = new List<String>();
for(Custom_Settings__c c : Custom_Settings__c.getValues()) {
    dontshowstatus.add(c.Name);
cls.Dont_Show_Lead_With_Status__c = dontshowstatus;
```

The values from custom settings will be assigned to list of string and then assigned to `cls.Dont_Show_Lead_With_Status__c`.

Hope it helps.